# How to establish one-to-one connection between the clients using signalr?

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

I was developing a webapplication using signalr but i am having problem sending text to specific user in the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following :

```
Clients.Client(ConnectionId).OnMessage(MessageText)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get current signalr hub

```
private IHubContext _hub =GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SignalRHubName>()
```

Send Message to client by invoking the method in client side

```
  _hub.Clients.Client(signalrconnectionId).signalRMethodInClient(message);
```

Since you want to send a message to a specific client you can keep a mapping between singalrid and your client id and use that mapping to get the signalrconnectionId for a client when needed.